# CMS + BEM css together without using nesting css

Tags: css, sass, content-management-system, bem

I have a module that shows up in two different areas of the layout in the CMS. The problem is I want to have a different background color on the div.

Is there a way to accomplish that without the user having to add classes manually or any nesting css (I want the module css to stay self contained)?

Comment: actually nesting is just fine to solve this: https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#nested-selectors

Comment: But what my problem is that I have 1 component (controlled by a CMS) that is used in two different areas of the page and depending on it's parent container I want to change the background color. For this reason I can't just add new modifier classes to the html. However I don't want something like `.parent > .module.`

Comment: But that's exactly how it should be implemented. The module itself should not know anything about the context. That's the parent who should be responsible for such modifications. There's even a page on bem.info describing this case but it's only in Russian ATM so you may try machine translated version: https://translate.yandex.com/translate?url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.bem.info%2Fmethodology%2Fblock-modification%2F&lang=ru-en